# different results on a mysql query in php than in just mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

Hello i am having a difficult time realizing what is going wrong..

When i run this statement in mysql..

```
select brand_id,   brand_name,   
max(case when group_row_number = 1 then linecode end) Code1,   
max(case when group_row_number = 2 then linecode end) Code2,   
max(case when group_row_number = 3 then linecode end) Code3,   
max(case when group_row_number = 4 then linecode end) Code4,   
max(case when group_row_number = 5 then linecode end) Code5,   
max(case when group_row_number = 6 then linecode end) Code6,   
max(case when group_row_number = 7 then linecode end) Code7,   
max(case when group_row_number = 8 then linecode end) Code8,   
max(case when group_row_number = 9 then linecode end) Code9,   
max(case when group_row_number = 10 then linecode end) Code10 
from (   select brand_id,     brand_name,     linecode,     
@num := if(@brand_id = `brand_id` AND @brand_name = `brand_name`, @num + 1, 1) as 
group_row_number,     @brand_id := `brand_id` as dummy,   
@brand_name := `brand_name` as linedummy   from linecodes_temp ) 
src group by brand_id, brand_name order by if(linecode = '' or linecode is null,1,0), 
brand_name ASC;
```

i recieve the results back that i want.

```
  +----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| brand_id | brand_name                                         | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Code5 | Code6 | Code7 | Code8 | Code9 | Code10 |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| DPQT     | 1-800 Tow Truck                                    | DCF   | DCA   | AAA   | DDD   | DER   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
| BLGR     | 1-800-Radiator                                     | Curt  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
| BGVM     | 100+ Manufacturing/Coyote                          | ASC   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
| DPQS     | 10C Technologies Inc                               | ASQ   | AQW   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
| FDJG     | 2 Cool AirVents                                    | CAS   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
| DWFD     | 31 Incorporated                                    | ASD   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
| BBBB     | 3M                                                 | snoop | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
```

This is perfect.

But then when i turn around and call it in php.

```
$result = mysql_query("select brand_id,   brand_name,   max(case when group_row_number = 1 then linecode end) Code1,   max(case when group_row_number = 2 then linecode end) Code2,   max(case when group_row_number = 3 then linecode end) Code3,   max(case when group_row_number = 4 then linecode end) Code4,   max(case when group_row_number = 5 then linecode end) Code5,   max(case when group_row_number = 6 then linecode end) Code6,   max(case when group_row_number = 7 then linecode end) Code7,   max(case when group_row_number = 8 then linecode end) Code8,   max(case when group_row_number = 9 then linecode end) Code9,   max(case when group_row_number = 10 then linecode end) Code10 from (   select brand_id,     brand_name,     linecode,      @num := if(@brand_id = `brand_id` AND @brand_name = `brand_name`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,     @brand_id := `brand_id` as dummy,     @brand_name := `brand_name` as linedummy   from linecodes_temp ) src group by brand_id, brand_name order by if(linecode = '' or linecode is null,1,0), brand_name ASC",$dbh);
```

and do a

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

and go through the table

the results i get are

```
 brand_id       brand_name                  Code1   Code2 Code3 Code4 Code5 to Code 10
 DPQT           1-800 Tow Truck             DER         
 BLGR           1-800-Radiator              Curt            
 BGVM           100+ Manufacturing/Coyote   ASC         
 DPQS           10C Technologies Inc        ASQ         
 FDJG           2 Cool AirVents             CAS         
 DWFD           31 Incorporated             ASD         
 BBBB           3M                          snoop
```

When i do a var_dump($row) the results from the php query above show up so i know i am not doing anything wrong in that aspect

I am using the exact same query in both mysql and php i am assuming there is a syntax difference in php when calling mysql_query that i am missing

if anyone could help i would be very thankful

Thank you for your time.

Comment: show your display code, e.g. `var_dump($row)` within your fetch loop. it is highly unlikely that simply running this from PHP would change the results.

Comment: i just did the results come back the same. as the table i posted about from php.

Comment: So you don't get any other codes except for the first one 'Code1'? Is that correct? Just an FYI, for security reasons the use of mysql commands are discouraged in favor of the more secure mysqli commands.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB.  Check your loop logic to make sure everything is happening as you would expect.

Comment: i converted it to mysqli and same results

Answer (score 0):

Include the column `group_row_number` in your selected columns and echo them, to see whether this really works as expected.

Another difference might be in `linecodes_temp`, depending on how this is setup in either the plain MySQL or PHP version.

I rewrote your subselect into

```
$sql0 = 'set @num := 0';
$result = mysql_query($sql0, $dbh);
// error handling
$sql = 'select brand_id, brand_name, @num := @num + 1 as group_row_number from linecodes_temp';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbh);
// error handling
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // process result set
}
```

and now group_row_number increases as expected.

Comment: i went through and the linecodes_temp is exactly how it should be

Comment: @user1863457 And what about group_row_number? Are they in ascending order as well?

Comment: from above is the query i used in mysql and it came back with the correct results. I can't seem to understand why it changed... why calling the mysql_query in php

Comment: @user1863457 I just tried your subselect (the part with group_row_number) in both MySQL and PHP. And in *both* cases group_row_number was *always* 1. Please look at the suggested rewrite of the subselect in my answer.

Comment: now i need to figure out how make a correct if statement in order for this to work. When brand_id and brand_name change that the num goes back to 0

Comment: @user1863457 Embarrassing, I completely misunderstood your select and now DRapp's answer makes perfectly sense. :$

Answer (score 0):

Your inner-most prequery where you have

```
          @brand_name := `brand_name` as linedummy   
       from 
          linecodes_temp ) src
```

You need to add your ORDER BY clause here

```
          @brand_name := `brand_name` as linedummy   
       from 
          linecodes_temp
       order by
          `brand_id`, `brand_name` ) src
```

if you dont, the inner query reads the data in raw order which may have them staggered from ID 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, etc..  every time it switches back, it resets your counter back to 1 thus overwriting your previous setting of Code 1.

You MAY even need to add the counter to the OUTER result AFTER the inner order by.

Comment: i tried what you told me to do. And still the same results as before.

Comment: i just don't understand why in mysql i get the correct results but in php i don't